# trouble referencing a struct in header file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I'm trying to use a struct declared in my header file, but when I compile I get the error message "cpu.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `reg' "

Basically I defined the struct in the header to make access easier and after clearing some errors, I attempted to compile my project but any reference to the struct in the header file gives the same error message as above.

```
/* in header file */

struct Registers {

  int PC;
  int IR0;
  int IR1;
  int AC;
  int MAR;
  int MBR;
  int Base;

};

extern struct Registers reg;
```

```
/* in cpu file */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "computer.h"
int m_addr;

void cpu_execute_instruction() {

  switch (reg.IR0) {
  
    case '0':
      
      reg.IR0 = 0;
      reg.PC++;
      
      break;
      
    case '1':
      
      reg.AC = reg.IR1;
      reg.PC++;
      
      break;
/* switch continues further */
```

Comment: `extern struct Registers reg;` declares that there is a reg defined somewhere that can be referenced. That is good, but you also need a definition `struct Registers reg;` in exactly one compilation unit (.c file) to actually create it.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `extern` keyword you have *declared* your variable `reg` but you have not *defined* it anywhere. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) for the detail explanation. You need to define the variable in your `.c` file:

```
/* in cpu file */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "computer.h"
int m_addr;
struct Registers reg;

void cpu_execute_instruction() {

  switch (reg.IR0) {
  
    case '0':
      
      reg.IR0 = 0;
      reg.PC++;
      
      break;
      
    case '1':
      
      reg.AC = reg.IR1;
      reg.PC++;
      
      break;
/* switch continues further */
```